# What does it mean to say $f(x) \sim g(x)$, i.e. $f(x)$ behaves like $g(x)$ when $x \to \infty$?

Tags: calculus, limits, asymptotics

If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty$, then $f$ grows faster than $g$. Same if $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{g(x)}{f(x)} = 0$.

Would $f$ behave like $g$ if
$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$ ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis),

> $$f(x) \sim g(x) \quad \mbox{as} \quad  x \to \infty$$

means

> $$\lim_{ x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$

Comment: Just wanted to emphasize that the symbol $\sim$ does not have any further meaning than the above limit. Many people try to make it more "intuitive" by saying that "$f(x)$ behaves like $g(x)$" as $x \to \infty$ and hence $f(x)$ can be replaced by $g(x)$ in limit evaluations. But such "intuitions" are nothing more than source of utter confusions and hence one should steer clear of such notions. +1 from my end.